# Using sys.argv[1] in a SQL command in a python script

Tags: python, sql

I'm writing a utility to query a database based on an asset number.  I can't seem to get the correct syntax for the SQL portion of the script.

The syntax would be # python labgetter.py 1234

```
SQL = ("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CmdbDetails] WHERE AreaName = '%s'"), (sys.argv[1]))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried:

```
   ID=sys.argv[1]
   SQL = ("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CmdbDetails] WHERE AreaName = 'ID'"))
```

The script does not recognize ID as a variable.  Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings).

EDITTED:
I changed the code to a full working snippet with the [argparse library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

```
import argparse


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("db_id", help="The db id of AreaName", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    sql_query = f"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CmdbDetails] WHERE AreaName = '{args.db_id}'"
    print(sql_query)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: the ID comes from user input on the command line.  It's not hard coded.

Comment: @teamg I edited the code to add the argparse part.

Comment: @Franco_Morero:  I get the following error: python labGetter.py 8522
                                                                                       
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @teamg Did you copy this same code or are you adding additional code? Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8.1 and no syntax errors are founds. If you give me more context maybe I can help you.

Comment: @Franco_Morero Ah, I'm using python 2.7.  That may be the difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231431/discussion-between-franco-morero-and-teamg).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use `sys.argv` or can you `input` from the `cmd` line instead?

```
ID = input("Enter ID: ")
SQL = f"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CmdbDetails] WHERE AreaName = '{ID}'"
print(SQL)


Enter ID: Area_55
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CmdbDetails] WHERE AreaName = 'Area_55'
```

Comment: I can use your example but want to use sys.argv so I can run it in a for loop without a prompt for the ID each time.